# How to use the registration procedure of FOSUserBundle from a third controller

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

**I have to persist an entity (let's call it `Entity` for simplicity) in the database that has to be referenced to a `User` handled with FOSUserBundle.** To make this reference I have a column `entity_table.userId`.

**When the new `Entity` is created, I have to:**

1. **Create the `User`** through the registration procedure of FosUserBundle;
2. **Get the ID of the new created User**: [*meta code*] `$userId = $get->newCreatedUserId()`;
3. **Set this id in `Entity`:** `$entity->setUserId($userId)`;
4. Persist the `Entity` to the database.

**How can I integrate the registration procedure of FosUserBundle into the controller that persists my `Entity`?**

**MORE DETAILS**

In the first time I tried to simply copy the code from the method registerAction() of the RegistrationController of FOSUserBundle: a quick and dirty approach that, anyway didn't work as i get an error as the User class i passed was wrong (I passed my custom `User` entity I use to overwrite the bundle).

This kind of approach has also other drawbacks:

- I cannot control the registration procedure (send or decide to not send confirmation e-mails, for example);
- I cannot use the builtin checks on passed data;
- I cannot be sure that on FOSUserBundles updates my custom method continue to work
- Others I cannot imagine at the moment...

**So, I'd like to create the user in the cleanest way possible: how can i do this? Which should be a good approach?**

1. A controller forwarding?
2. Anyway, an "hardcoded" custom method that emulates the registerAction() method?
3. A custom registration form?

I have read a lot of discussions here at StackOverflow and on Internet, I read the documentation of FOSUserBundle and of Symfony too, but I cannot decide for the good approach, also because I'm not sure I have understood all the pros and cons of each method.

**If someone can put me on the right way... :)**

**SOMETHING MORE ABOUT MY REGISTRATION FLOW**

I have a getStarted procedure handled by the controller GetStarteController.
In it I have two methods:

1. indexAction(), that displays a registration form with only the field "email";
2. endAction(), that receive the form and creates a Company using the passed e-mail (it gets the domain part only of the email).

**HERE IS A WORKING MESSY CODE** (inside it for Companies and Stores are called some methods that exists in the source code but are not in the posted classes below, as setBrand() or setUrl(), for example).

```
// AppBundle/Controller/getStartedController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use MyVendor\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Companies;
use AppBundle\Entity\Stores;

class GetStartedController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("getstarted")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $data = array();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data, array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('getStartedEnd'),
            ))
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("getstarted/end", name="getStartedEnd")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function endAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
        } else {
            /** @todo here we have to raise some sort of exception or error */
            echo 'no data submitted (See the todo in the code)';exit;
        }

        // Pass the email to the template
        $return['email'] = $data['email'];

        // Get the domain part of the email and pass it to the template
        $domain = explode('@', $data['email']);
        $return['domain'] = $domain[1];

        // 1) Create the new user
        $user = new User();

        // Get the token generator
        $tokenGenerator = $this->container->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');

        $user->setEmail($return['email']);
        $userRandomUsername = substr($tokenGenerator->generateToken(), 0, 12);
        $user->setUsername('random-' . $userRandomUsername);

        $plainPassword = substr($tokenGenerator->generateToken(), 0, 12);
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);

        // Set the password for the user
        $user->setPassword($encoded);

        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        // Perstist the user in the database
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        $userId = $user->getId();

        // 2) Create the Company object
        $company = new Companies();
        $company->setBrand($return['domain'])
            ->setAdded(new \DateTime())
            ->setOwnerId($userId);

        // 3) Create the Store object
        $store = new Stores();
        $store->setEmail($return['email'])
            ->setUrl($return['domain'])
            ->setAdded(new \DateTime());

        // Get the Entity Manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // Persist Company and get its ID
        $em->persist($company);
        $em->flush();
        $return['companyId'] = $company->getId();

        // Set the property branchOf of the Store object
        $store->setBranchOf($return['companyId']);

        // Persist the Store object
        $em->persist($store);
        $em->flush();

        $return['storeId'] = $store->getId();

        return $return;
    }
}
```

Here the User Entity that ovewrites the one provided by FOSUserBundle

```
// MyVendor/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace MyVendor\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="prefix_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Some essential code of Companies.php

```
// AppBundle/Entity/Companies.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Companies
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="companies")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Companies
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ownerId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $ownerid;

    /**
     * Set ownerid
     *
     * @param integer $ownerid
     * @return Companies
     */
    public function setOwnerid($ownerid)
    {
        $this->ownerid = $ownerid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ownerid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getOwnerid()
    {
        return $this->ownerid;
    }
}
```

Some essential code of Stores.php

```
// AppBundle/Entity/Stores.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Stores
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="stores", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="branchOf", columns={"branchOf"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Stores
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="branchOf", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $branchof;

    /**
     * Set branchof
     *
     * @param integer $branchof
     * @return Stores
     */
    public function setBranchof($branchof)
    {
        $this->branchof = $branchof;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get branchof
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getBranchof()
    {
        return $this->branchof;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom registration form but the best way is clearly to listen to registration event dispatched by FOSUser.

Here is an example :

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * L'entity manager
     *
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Constructeur de l'EventListener
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager
     */
   public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE => 'onRegistrationInit',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Triggered when FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE is caught.
     *
     * @param \FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent $userEvent
     */
    public function onRegistrationInit(UserEvent $userEvent)
    {
        $user = $userEvent->getUser();
        // Define your own logic there
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make this listener a service:

```
#services.yml
services:
    oe_user.registration:
        class: OrienteExpress\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
        # arguments are optional but you still can need them 
        # so I let the EM as example which is an often used parameter
        arguments:
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

You'll find the complete list of event dispatched by FOSUser [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php)

Moreover, Symfony entities are a model of objects. That said, you need to understand that you don't work with ids within your model, but object.

You should not use thing such as $var->setUserId() within entites. Doctrine is there to manage your relations, so be carefull about this. You might face unexpected problem by not using Symfony & Doctrine the way it has been designed for.

**EDIT:**

In your company entity, your relation is beetween a Company and a User objects. That means you dont need a User id in your company but just a instance of User.

I think you might go back to the basics before wanting to do advanced stuff.

Your relation beetween the user and the company should not be designed by an integer attribute but a real doctrine relation.

Ex:

```
class Company {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Path\To\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
     private $owner;

     /**
      * @param $user User 
      */
     public function setUser(User $user)
     {
         $this->user = $user;
     }
}
```

Then when you'll create a new company. You won't need to know the User's id or even insert it to make the link between them. But if you are not aware yet of this, once again, I think you should go back to the basics of Symfony since this is one of the most (maybe the most) important feature to master.

Comment: Hi Gregory, thank you for your reply. I think i cannot listen for the registration event, as i the procedure doesn't start from FOSUserBundle, but from my form integrated into a separate registration procedure. The app is designed to make the registration of Entity (that is a company for which i receive only a business email), not of the user. I need to create the user "only" to provide access to company through login. So the center point is the company and not the user.

Comment: I have updated my question to better explain (I hope I have!) how I designed my registration flow.

Comment: Your workflow seems to be fitting the event listening method perfectly. Just use the FOSUser registration form to register the user (will end with a simple registration form you'll set the parameters you need). Then, in the listener, create the company as well as the store. And as I mentionned, dont think about id, think about object. When you create a graph of object, you don't need id. Doctrine relation declaration will make the work to bind your object within the DB.

Comment: Gregory's approach is correct.  Assuming your User entity has a relationship (1:n, or m:n) with Company, you can  do `$user->setCompany($company)`.  If you posted your User & Company entities we might sketch out some code.

Comment: I updated the question with some code and a working class for GetStartedController. The code inside it is very messy I think. As i don't well understand what you are saying about listeners ( :) ) some sample code from you will be very useful! Thank you!

Comment: Eh eh, I know I'm a novice :) I'm just learning by practicing, thanks also to explanations like those!
So, if I have well understood, the same applies also to the Store entity, that I should write to accept a Company object...

The next step, then, is to move all the code that actually is in endAction() method, into the listener, so I have to create there Company and Store after I have created the user. Am I right?